# Functions into (or out of) spaces with the (co)discrete topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

a. Let $X$ be a space with the discrete topology. Characterize all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow X$. Characterize all continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

b. Let $X$ be a space with the indiscrete topology. Characterize all continuous functions $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: For (b), I thought that since $f^{-1}U$ must be either empty set or $\mathbb R$, f(x) must be $\mathbb R$. I don't really know how to do (a) tho

Comment: Also note that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ is any function, $X$ indiscrete, then $f^{-1}[X] = \mathbb{R}$ and $f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$, so $f$ is continuous always, as these are the only open sets of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuity means that the inverse image of any open set must be open.

So if $X$ is discrete and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is any function. Let $O$ be any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is $f^{-1}[O]$ open?

OTOH if $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ is continuous, then suppose that $f$ assumes more than one value. Say $f(x_1) = p \neq q =f(x_2)$. We know $O_1 = f^{-1}[\{p\}]$ and $O_2 = f^{-1}[X \setminus \{p\}]$ are both open in $\mathbb{R}$ by continuity (and all subsets of $X$ are open).  Hence $\mathbb{R}$ is a disjoint union of two open non-empty sets, so?

If $X$ is indiscrete and $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, for any open subset $O \subset \mathbb{R}$, either $f^{-1}[O] = \emptyset$ which happens exactly when $f[X] \cap O = \emptyset$, or when $O$ does contain some image point of $f$, $f^{-1}[O]$ is non-empty and open in $X$, so equals $X$, and then $f[X] \subset O$. So $f[X]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that either misses any open $O$ or is entirely contained in it. What subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are like that?

Comment: Alternatively, if $p \in f[X]$, then $f^{-1}[\{p\}]$ is non-empty open and closed in the reals...

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+and+codiscrete+topology), the forgetful functor $U: \mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Sets}$ which forgets the topology has both a left and a right adjoint: the discrete functor $\mathrm{disc}: \mathsf{Sets} \to \mathsf{Top}$ is the left adjoint, and the codiscrete (or indiscrete) functor $\mathrm{codisc}: \mathsf{Sets} \to \mathsf{Top}$ is the right adjoint.

If you look at the definition of an [adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) in terms of a bijection of Hom-sets, this characterizes the discrete and indiscrete topology in terms of what the continuous maps are.